# Testing Observable Field Changes within a Coroutine

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am writing unit tests and I have this particular case when I change observable value before executing a suspend function and then right after. I would like to write a unit test to check if the value was changes twice correctly.

Here is the method:

```
 fun doSomething() {
            viewModelScope.launch(ioDispatcher) {
                try {
                    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        commandLiveData.value = Pair(CANCEL_TIMER, null)
                    }
                    isProgress.set(true) //need to test it was set to true in one test
                    checkoutInteractor.doSomethingElse().run {
                        handleResult(this)
                    }
                    isProgress.set(false) //need to test it was set to false here in another test
                } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
                    handleHttpError(ex)
                    isProgress.set(false)
                }
            }
        }
```

When writing a test I am calling `doSomething()` but **I am unsure how to detect that the value was set to true before the `checkoutInteractor.doSomethingElse` call and set to false after.**

Here is the test I have

```
@Test
    fun `test doSomething enables progress`() {
        runBlockingTest {
            doReturn(Response()).`when`(checkoutInteractor). checkoutInteractor.doSomethingElse()
            viewModel.doSomething()
            assertTrue(viewModel.isProgress.get()) //fails obviously as the value was already set to false after the `doSomethingElse` was executed. 
        }
    }
```

BTW, `isProgress` is an `ObservableBoolean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to either mock or spy on `isProgress` and `checkoutInteractor` fields to record and verify the execution of their methods.

1. Pass a mock or spy for `isProcess` and `checkoutInteractor` into your class.
2. Execute `doSomething()`
3. Verify [inOrder](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html#in_order_verification) the `set()` and `doSomethingElse()` functions

Example:

```
@Test
fun `test doSomething enables progress`() {
    runBlockingTest {
        val checkoutInteractor = Mockito.spy(CheckoutInteractor())
        val isProcess = Mockito.spy(ObservableBoolean(true))
        val viewModel = ViewModel(isProcess, checkoutInteractor)

        viewModel.doSomething()

        val inOrder = inOrder(isProcess, checkoutInteractor)
        inOrder.verify(isProcess).set(true)
        inOrder.verify(checkoutInteractor).doSomethingElse()
        inOrder.verify(isProcess).set(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: checkoutInteractor is already a mock, isProgress is a field in viewmodel, it doesn't make sense to bring it to the constructor level as it is one of 20 fields. but I didn't know there is inOrder api. I will try it out

Comment: to maybe help the others, I didn't pass my field into the constructor I just stabbed it like so  `when`(viewModel.isProgress).thenReturn(mock(ObservableBoolean::class.java)) , view model is already a spy

Comment: @Rainmaker 1. My example was - well - an example, so you can pass the variables and fields however you like. 2. Be careful not to mock too much in your test. Consider spying as a valid option, as well as dummy objects (stubs).